# Using Colormap feature with Pandas.DataFrame.Plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, colormap

```
from matplotlib import cm
a = pd.DataFrame(zip(ranFor.feature_importances_, trainSet.columns))
a = a.sort_values(by = [0], ascending= False)
tinydata = a.iloc[:25]
tinydata = tinydata[::-1]
tinydata.set_index([1], inplace=True)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
colors = cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(tinydata)))
tinydata.plot(kind = 'barh', figsize = (15,10), title = 'Most Important 20 Features of the Initial Model',
                    grid = True, legend = False, color = colors)
plt.xlabel('Feature Importance')
plt.show()
```

Hello everyone, this is my code for plotting a bar plot. The problem is I couldn't figure out how to plot the colors with colormap with an increasing transparency like the graph I am attaching to my question. Thank you.

[image: The graph I mentioned]

EDIT

```
colors = cm.Reds(np.linspace(0,len(tinydata),1))
tinydata.plot(kind = 'barh', figsize = (15,10), title = 'Most Important 20 Features of the Initial Model',
                    grid = True, legend = False, color = colors)
```

I made a change like this and I guess it worked but the colors are really pale. How can I change this.

Comment: It is same in terms of values, but the color patttern is the same of the largest column instead I want it to be more transparent as the value gets smaller.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that pandas does not provide this functionality. Although they say [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html) that `color` can take an array, this refers to different columns, as we can also see in this example:

```
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tinydata = pd.DataFrame({"ind": list("ABCDEF"), 
                         "X": [10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1], 
                         "Y": [5,  3, 4, 2, 3, 1],
                         "Z": [8,  5, 9, 6, 7, 3] })
tinydata = tinydata[::-1].set_index("ind")
n = len(tinydata)
colors = cm.Reds(np.linspace(0.2, 0.8, 3))
tinydata.plot(kind = 'barh', figsize = (15,10), title = 'Most Important 20 Features of the Initial Model',
                    grid = True, legend = True, color = colors)
plt.xlabel('Feature Importance')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

In the context of pandas providing commonly used plotting functions, this makes sense. So, for your application, it is back to the multifunctionality of [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html) on which pandas relies anyhow:

```
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tinydata = pd.DataFrame({"ind": list("ABCDEF"), 
                         "X": [10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1]})
tinydata = tinydata[::-1].set_index("ind")
n = len(tinydata)
colors = cm.Reds(np.linspace(0, 1, n))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,10))
ax.barh(tinydata.index, tinydata.X, color = colors)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('Feature Importance')
ax.set_title('Most Important 20 Features of the Initial Model',)
plt.show()
```

Output:[image]